# Elastic Beanstalk: No module named settings

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to run a django app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and I'm following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-configure-for-eb) tutorial.

However, when deploying, I get a 500 error, and when looking at the logs:

```
ImportError: No module named settings
[Tue Sep 06 15:22:32.138981 2016] [:error] [pid 1940] [remote 127.0.0.1:42845] mod_wsgi (pid=1940): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/fasttext/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Tue Sep 06 15:22:32.139006 2016] [:error] [pid 1940] [remote 127.0.0.1:42845] mod_wsgi (pid=1940): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/fasttext/wsgi.py'.
```

It seems like my wsgi.py file is the issue:

```
"""
WSGI config

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I read many topics on SO and other sites, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Here is my .ebextensions/django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: fasttext/wsgi.py
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your folder/file layout?  I'm wondering if there's a `/fasttext/__init__.py` file?

Comment: Are you specifying your settings file?
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "path_to_settings.settings"

Comment: your wsgi.py specifies setting path as `("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")` which I'm guessing should be `("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "fasttext.settings")`

Comment: @Graham Were you able to resolve this?